# Can I get invited to the iOS Developer Programm and then manage everything on my own?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

An acquaintance and I like to publish an iOS app to the Apple App Store.
Can he enroll into the iOS Developer Programm ($99/year) with his AppleID and invite my AppleID as a member, then make me an admin, so that I am able to develop/ publish and maintain everything without his help? Or do I need to enroll, too?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: you want to publish in your name as a different developer?

Comment: The App will get published on my acuaintance's name. We are both developing. I just want to make sure, that he can give me admin rights to be able to mange everything the same as he can.

Comment: @dminones. Why did you ask. Do you see a problem?

Comment: Just to be sure want do you want to achieve. Will answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Instructions for that can be found in the apple developer guides

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers.html

Comment: So, just my acuaintance has to pay?

Comment: Yes and then add you and your email as an administrator to give you the same rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can be invited to join to another account. What you need to have in mind is the following.

You definitely can by invited to be part of a team as developer and manage apps.
There is anyhow some considerations:
Two kind of users needed to develop and publish an App Store App.

**Developer Account**: Required to upload apps, create profiles, certificates, etc.
**iTunesConnect account**: Required to create apps, user management, etc.

When somebody enrols on iOSDeveloperProgram gets both users with the same login, but if you want to be invited you need to be invited both (this can be an issues if you own some other itunesconnect account becouse must be unique)

Comment: My acquaintance also needs an iTunesConnect account, which is used to publish apps? Can we both access the same iTunesConnect account and change i. e. the app description by using both your AppleIDs?

Comment: Yes, the one who enrols will have an iTunesConnect account wich is what you need to create and edit apps. If your acquaintance invites you to manage their itunesconnect team account you will be able yo edit and create apps the same way he will

Comment: iTunesConnect is for publish apps. Developer Account is for developing apps. Are you mixing these two?

Comment: True, but I'n not mixing these becouse in order to upload a build from XCode you need to have a developer account (wich could or not be the same that the used in iTunesConnect)